QWebEngineView renders bokeh vizualisation with largish data (~18000 points) slowly
I'm trying to include a Bokeh based visualisation canvas in a Qt application written in Python (using PySide6).  So I create the visualisation, save it in an HTML file, and read it in a QWebEngineView widget.  It renders fine, but is extremely sluggish to interact with it; e.g. try selecting the zoom tool and zooming in, or panning.  The surprising part is, when I open the same HTML in Firefox, it is pretty snappy, as I would expect.
There are 2 time series, with 8760 data points each in the plot.  What is going on here?
Minimal example
from argparse import ArgumentParser
from pathlib import Path


from PySide6.QtCore import QUrl, QSize
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PySide6.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, path: str = "", *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if path:
            self.browser = QWebEngineView()
            self.browser.setUrl(QUrl.fromLocalFile(Path(path).absolute()))
            self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)
            self.resize(QSize(800, 500))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # HTML example produced using Bokeh: dump-viz.html
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("file")
    opts = parser.parse_args()

    app = QApplication()
    window = MainWindow(opts.file)
    window.show()
    app.exec()

The above script, and an example HTML is available in this gist.
You can run it with hatch run pyside-qwebengine-slow.py qwebengine-ex-viz.html, or create a virtual env, then pip install PySide6, and run normally.
Additional info
The code that I use to generate that plot, is more or less equivalent to:
def make_plot(data_list)
    """`data_list`: list of dataclasses representing a time series;
    data.y, data.labels, etc.
    """
    palette = TolRainbow[10]
    cds = ColumnDataSource(data=pd.DataFrame({data.labels[0]: data.y for data in data_list}))
    legend_items = {}
    fig = figure(x_axis_label="x_label", y_axis_label="y_label", title="title", height=400, width=800)
    for idx, data in enumerate(data_list):
        line = fig.line("index", data.labels[0], source=cds, color=palette[idx])
        point = fig.scatter("index", data.labels[0], source=cds, color=palette[idx], size=7)
        legend_items[data.labels[0]] = [line, point]

    legend = Legend(items=list(legend_items.items()))
    fig.add_layout(legend, "right")
    fig.legend.click_policy = "hide"
    return fig

fig = make_plot(data_list)
html = file_html(fig, INLINE, title)


I would not expect two line and two scatter calls with ~9k points each to be especially slow. Can you confirm that data_list is really length two? You are duplicating all the data unnecessarily, though by passing df source to both glyphs. That results in two sepaeate CDS objects with the same data. You should create one ColumnDataSource from the df at the top of the loop, and pass that to avoid duplication. All that said, there are no resources in the project to do any testing whatsoever with Qt web engines, so there is no particular expection with respect to that environment.

@bigreddot In my original problem data_list is ~10.  But for my minimal example I reduced it to 2.  The slow down is more severe for 10.  After posting the question, I refactored the bokeh snippet to use 1 CDS.  It reduces the size of the html by about half.  But qualitatively I see a similar slow down (I'll edit the question & gist).  Thanks for noting that this use is untested.  Could you suggest what could be the reason, e.g. available memory, missing browser capability, etc?  Then I could look for any configuration in Qt to tweak that.

I am unable to speculate offhand. I have never used QTWebView so I can't really comment about it's configuration or capability relative to other browsers. Does QTWebView support webgl? If so you might try enabling that in the Bokeh code.

@bigreddot thanks, it does indeed support webgl.  I'll check if it's enabled.  I'm also new to this, but so far I've gathered Qt WebView is a wrapper around chromium.
